# Is my answer so improbable or too low quality?

Tags: discussion, down-votes, low-quality, self-answer

I asked a question and it was answered. However, I figured out that the origin was completely different and the circumstances will be hard to figure out, so [I answered my own question](https://superuser.com/a/1006118/384054), describing the real cause.

My answer was at -2 and a comment was made, indicating that the answer might be unclear. So I edited it to add more detail.

Is the answer now clear enough? If not, why not? I'd like to learn giving good answers on SuperUser, but maybe the rules are a bit different to Stack Overflow, so I appreciate any guidance.

Comment: Your answer is fine (especially after your revision). The downvoters may not have seen the revised answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While the whole story and your own solutions to the whole of the problem is (now) answered, the original question had left out the whole of the problem and concentrated on if your product is a clone or not.

The original question would have been better if it was asked to HP the maker of the product itself, what is to stop the same software/firmware from being used on a clone , like that hasnt been done before :-)  So you really cant prove it :-)

An answer was provided for the titled question,  your commenting answer then provides many layers more information about the whole situation. There is no comment or accept for the answer (be it the answer or not) on the original question?  (at least part of) The Question still left unresolved, was the Jarmund answer provided helpfull and correct for the titled question?

There is no answer By You in the self answer that the product is the HP product you thought you bought, or a clone still?  There is just your solutining the original problem, you did not concentrate on asking to begin with.

This is what I am seeing , how it is done/edited at the time of my writing. 
There is an Anally retentive position on SU that **the answer be an answer to the question that was asked**.  IMO (instead) I think the important data that a person could gain from any question, is any Information or solutions to problems discovered, when searching on the web , when having a problem.

Conclusion: Do you feel that the information you provided , will help other people with the original question, or the problem that you were having when asking the question?  If you have therin helped other people, all you have to do next is Ignore the stupid rep points system and go on about helping others. If the opposite is true that this is just a pile of text that people will find when searching the web that solutions nothing, then make it so it does.

Answer (score 8):

I think the cause of this is that you asked a question about a presumed solution, instead of the actual problem.

You asked "how to tell if it's cloned?", instead of concentrating on the actual problem "why does my switch report different model numbers, and incorrect information, in different parts of the UI?".

Your answer would answer the latter, not what was actually asked.

If you had asked the latter, you may have even received the answer to the former as a possible solution.

Having said all that, both your question and answer are constructed well, and understandable (aside from a few spelling mistakes/typos, but whatever ;) ).  They were both good, they just ended up not belonging together.

Comment: Inline with this answer which I agree with, none of the answers to the link question really answer the question "What steps can I take to identify if I have a real or pirated product?" so that is an indication the real question is something else (which in my opinion be actually asked) entirely.  I should also point out that a pirated product could indicate whatever it wanted in software, so that question, is extremely hard to actually answer.

Comment: In agreement and sum-up:  The question is malformed.  It asks the wrong question(s).  The answer helps solve the problem, which is totally not what was asked.  Edit the question such that it begs the answer, problem solved.  (in logic discussions, that's a cheat, but for distributing knowledge it works fairly well)